# Postgres selecting distinct value from one column and insert into table

Tags: postgresql

I am not able to select distinct store_id from the table in postgres..

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong - try using `DISTINCT ON` (more info [here](https://www.noelherrick.com/blog/postgres-distinct-on))

If you want to maintain the column order you can do a nested select

Comment: There, try that

Comment: Any luck with that?